# My c program ends before it runs the loop in the function

Tags: c

Im trying to run my c code,This code keep ending as soon as i press the return button (new line):

> realloc Way - press 1  linked List way - press 2 (or any other key):
>   1
>
> Enter chars and to finish push new line: Program ended with exit
>   code: 0

if i just copy the function to the main then i have no problems and it runs good.
Am i missing something?
Im using xcode.
Thank you

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    printf ("\n realloc Way - press 1\n linked List way - press 2 (or any other key):\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    if(a=='1') reallocWay();
    else linkedListWay();
    return 0;
}  
void reallocWay()
{
    char *data,*temp;
    data=malloc(sizeof(char));
    char c; /* c is the current character */
    int i; /* i is the counter */
    printf ("\n Enter chars and to finish push new line:\n");
    for (i=0;;i++) {
        c=getchar(); /* put input character into c */
        if (c== 'q') /* break from the loop on new line */
            break;
        data[i]=c; /* put the character into the data array */
        temp=realloc(data,(i+2)*sizeof(char)); /* give the pointer some memory */
        if ( temp != NULL ) {
            data=temp;
        } else {
            free(data);
            printf("Error allocating memory!\n");
            return ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you declared `reallocWay` before `main`?

Comment: @benwad That wouldn't cause that behaviour, though. Most compilers I've seen would assume `int reallocWay(void)` if undeclared (and warn).

Comment: True. I didn't see he said Xcode so I assumed it was an instance of MSVC's "I know what you mean" behaviour...

Answer (score 3):

Problem is with

```
if(a=='1') // You are comparing with character insteda of int
    reallocWay();
```

you have to compare like this

```
if(a==1) // Compare with integer. 
    reallocWay();
```

Remember `"Single Quote for Single Character"`